# angular2-multiselect-dropdown - Validation

Tags: angular, html, validation, angular-forms

I want to perform a validation to check if at least one option is selected from the multi-select drop-down (i am using  this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown). I am using html5 required validation rules to check whether the form is valid or not using angular4.

it is becoming valid when I check at least one from the drop-down. but when I unselect all the form is not becoming invalid.
the code for validating the same is given below

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown item-width="100" name="rolesSelected" tabindex="21" id="selRoles" [options]="roleOptions" aria-required="true" 
        [(ngModel)]="userDetails.roles">
</ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

to check at least an item is selected or not you will have to check whether the *userDetails.roles* have length more than 1.